# How to change jQuery toggle() status

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Using toogle to show/hide the div, I've got a problem that when I hide my div with anothor function, I have to click twice on the button to perform correct action.

Is there any way change the toggle switch like I clicked the button?

```
$('#add_task').toggle(function() { 
    if ($("#new_task_status").attr("value")==0) { 
        $("#new_task").slideDown();
        $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "1");
    }
}, function() {
    if ($("#new_task_status").attr("value")==1) { 
        $("#new_task").slideUp();
        $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "0");
    }
});


$('nav').click(function() { 
    if ($("#new_task_status").attr("value")==1) { 
        $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "0");
        $("#new_task").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) so it doesn't matter, like this:

```
$('#add_task').click(function() { 
  $("#new_task").slideToggle(function() {
    $("#new_task_status").val($(this).is(':visible') ? 1 : 0);
  });
});
```

This does a [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead, so the current state doesn't matter...when it finishes sliding, if it's shown (you opened it) you get a `1` in the input, otherwise you get a `0`.  Also, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for input setting, much easier and more universal (I'm assuming it's an input here since that's most likely).

Answer (score 1):

No, you would have to implement your own alternative to the toggle() function, which checks the current state of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need to use `toogle` at all. You can do the same with just a click handler:

```
$('#add_task').click(function() { 
    if ($("#new_task_status").attr("value")==0) { 
        $("#new_task").slideDown();
        $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "1");
    } else  {
        $("#new_task").slideUp();
        $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "0");
    }
});
```

and then:

```
$('nav').click(function() { 
    $('#add_task').click();
});
```

Btw. `nav` is not a HTML element. You probably mean `#nav` (maybe just a typo).

And as Nick already mentioned, consider to use `.val()`.

Comment: BTW your solution slides Up and Down in a cycle so it's waving :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an event-driven approch, like:

```
$("#add_task").bind({
    "toggle": function(e) {
    $("#add_task").trigger(($("#new_task_status").attr("value")==0) ? "open" : "close"););
},
"open": function(e) {
    $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "1");
    $("#new_task").slideDown();
},
"close": function(e) {
    $("#new_task_status").attr("value", "0");
    $("#new_task").slideUp();
}               
});

$("#nav").click(function() {
    $("#add_task").trigger("toggle");
});
```

Comment: This isn't the same as the OP has, clicking on `#nav` always *closes* the element, your solution causes i to toggle it.  You would need a `.trigger("close")` instead, but this seems a very convoluted way to not take advantage of the already defined functions...